# How to figure out what spec version of api is implemented

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jetty

I am migrating my app from jetty 7 to 9. jetty server 9 depends on org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016

I need to know what version of servlet-api is implemented by this artifact in order to add dependency on it. I want to add maven dependency only on api not implementation, so I could easily change servlet container later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google for Jetty documentation, click on the link, and find this page: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html, which indicates every Jetty version with the corresponding version of the servlet and JSP spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the best about jetty [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/). According to the [servlet api javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/package-summary.html)...

You have a few things to take care of.

Set your Servlet API version in your WEB-INF/web.xml

Ensure you use the appropriate Servlet API in your project for the version of Jetty you intend on running on.

```
Jetty 6 - Servlet API 2.4
Jetty 7 - Servlet API 2.5
Jetty 8 - Servlet API 3.0
Jetty 9 - Servlet API 3.0 (tracking 3.1 and will switch over to 3.1 when spec is finalized)
```

Grab the appropriate Servlet API jar file from maven

```xml
<!-- Servlet API 3.0 / OSGi bundle ready -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.v201112011016</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
```